# Create a column in the same table with data is the results of other columns in the same table SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Here is my `SALARY` table I need to create a table with these following columns:

```
    SALARY (ID, EMPID, HSL, BASICSAL, WORKDAY, ACTUALSAL)
```

The calculation for the `ACTUALSAL` is

```
ACTUALSAL = (HSL * BASICSAL) / 48 * WORKDAY
```

Is there any way to create this column within SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will do -

```
Alter Table TableName
Add ACTUALSAL As ((HSL * BASICSAL) / 48 * WORKDAY);
```

Comment: Thank you. I did a workaround using a trigger but I think it will affect the performance. This is perfect

Answer (score 0):

Create a `computed column` called `SALARY`

```
alter table SALARY add ACTUALSAL as (HSL*BASICSAL)/48*WORKDAY PERSISTED
```

Importance of `PERSISTED` in computed column can found [**here**](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/08/03/sql-server-computed-column-persisted-and-performance/)

Answer (score 0):

Add Actual salary as computed column. You can change column types as your need.

```
CREATE TABLE SALARY
(
ID INT,
EMPID INT,
HSL INT,
BASICSAL MONEY,
WORKDAY INT,
ActualSAL AS (HSL*BASICSAL)/48*WORKDAY
)
```